# Include one python file B inside file A where B uses variables defined in A

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project where I have multiple settings file which has lot of redundant data. The structure is as follows

**development.py**

```
app_one = 'http://localhost:8000'
app_two = 'http://localhost:9999'

abc_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_one)
xyz_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_two)
```

**staging.py**

```
app_one = 'http://staging.xyz.abc.com'
app_two = 'http://staging.pqr.abc.com'

abc_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_one)
xyz_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_two)
```

**production.py**

```
app_one = 'http://production.xyz.abc.com'
app_two = 'http://production.pqr.abc.com'

abc_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_one)
xyz_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_two)
```

In all the files `abc_url` and `xyz_url` are basically same url. The only thing that changes is the domain.

What I am looking to is,

- Put all urls in separate file called app_one_urls.py and app_two_urls.py
- Find a way to include this app_one_urls.py and app_two_urls.py in my development, staging and productions file

The final outcome can be as follows:

**app_one_urls.py**

```
abc_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_one)
```

**app_two_urls.py**

```
xyz_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_two)
```

are two separate files

in development.py I intend to do following

```
app_one = 'http://localhost:8000'
app_two = 'http://localhost:9999'
somehow get urls from app_one_urls and app_two_urls
```

Is it possible and feasible? If yes, I need help in understanding how.

Comment: Can you use relative urls, ` abc_url = '/some-url/'`? As you can see from the answers, it's possible, but it does involve quite a bit of code. Personally I would probably just suck it up and repeat the definition.

Comment: Can I suggest that during production, we need to save as many cycles as possible. Although it is harder work to update this every time, but it would be advisable rather than wasting valuable processing time needlessly

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to maintain separate files, you can define the configuration in dictionary, with `key` based on the environment type.

Here I am demonstrating based on `hostname`, as hostnames of my server differs like: `my-host-prod`, `my-host-staging`, `my-host-dev`. *You may use the condition which uniquely defines your server.*

```
import socket

def get_url_conf(my_host=socket.gethostname()):
    def get_conf_setting(env_type):
        return {'prod':    {'app1': 'app1_prod_url',
                            'app2': 'app2_prod_url'},
                'staging': {'app1': 'app1_staging_url',
                            'app2': 'app2_staging_url'},
                'dev':     {'app1': 'app1_dev_url',
                            'app2': 'app2_dev_url'},
                'local':   {'app1': 'app1_local_url',
                            'app2': 'app2_local_url'}
                }[env_type]
    if my_host.endswith('-prod'):
        server_key = 'prod'
    elif my_host.endswith('-staging'):
        server_key = 'prod'
    elif my_host.endswith('-dev'):
        server_key = 'dev'
    else:  # In case someone is running on local system
        server_key = 'local'
    return get_conf_setting(server_key)
```

Now in your settings file, you may call these as:

```
abc_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(get_url_conf()[`app1`])
xyz_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(get_url_conf()[`app2`])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is feasible.
You will need to arrange your settings as a module:

```
settings/
        /__init__.py
        /development.py
        /staging.py
        /production.py
        /base.py
```

Contents of base.py :

```
SOME_ENVIRONMENT_INDEPENDENT_SETTING = 1
```

Contents of development.py:

```
from base import *
SOME_DEVELOPMENT_SETTING = 1
app_one = 'http://localhost:8000'
app_two = 'http://localhost:9999'
```

Content of production.py:

```
    from base import *
    SOME_PRODUCTION_SETTING = 1
    app_one = 'http://production.xyz.abc.com'
    app_two = 'http://production.pqr.abc.com'
```

Content of `__init__.py`:

```
import os
#If you want to pull environment from an environment variable

#ENVIRONMENT = os.environ.get('CURR_ENV','PROD') 

ENVIRONMENT = "DEVELOPMENT"

if ENVIRONMENT == "PRODUCTION" :
    try:
        from production import *
    except:
        pass

elif ENVIRONMENT == "DEVELOPMENT" :
    try:
        from development import *
    except:
        pass

elif ENVIRONMENT == "STAGING":
    try:
        from staging import *
    except:
        pass

elif ENVIRONMENT.lower() == "DEVEL_LOCAL".lower():
    try:
        from devel_local import *
    except:
        pass

elif ENVIRONMENT.lower() == "PROD_PP".lower():
    try:
        from prod_pp import *
    except:
        pass


#common variables which change based on environment
abc_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_one)
xyz_url = '{0}/some-url/'.format(app_two)
```